# File .asm does not exist - atl transformation

Tags: xml, transformation, xmi

i am trying to do the sample transformation given in atl docu. but i am facing the problem once i run the transformation: `File family2person.asm does not exist` i dont have any clue what this means. i googled and found that .asm has something to do with assembler language. can anyone help me please, since atl is not that widespread language, forums cannot help me now. first i began the tutorial, then i renamed the .ecore files on the way, can that be the reason? trying to find the original asm file having another one in the hand?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the exact same problem; to solve it, I just created a new ATL-Project, copied the ecore metamodels that I had previously created and then, after creating the "family2person.atl" file, the .asm appeared by itself. From the documentation, it seems that this file is just a compiled version of the ATL file that you create, and is only generated when the atl you provide is correct ( although you should also make sure that your .ecore files pass the validation processes .... mine didn't and I had to adjust the cardinalities of some references, specially the EOpposite ones) ... check out this link, to find some more detailed technical info http://wiki.eclipse.org/ATL/User_Guide_-_The_ATL_Tools#Compiling_an_ATL_file.

Comment: Thanks for the link, this helped me find out how it works internally (see my answer)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it within your existing project. Create a new ATL project, open the `.project` file and copy the stuff there in your main project's `.project` file. (You'll probably need to close and reopen the project in eclipse)

In my case, the relevant stuff was, in the `<natures>` section:

```
<nature>org.eclipse.m2m.atl.adt.builder.atlNature</nature>
```

and in the `<buildSpec>` section:

```
<buildCommand>
    <name>org.eclipse.m2m.atl.adt.builder.atlBuilder</name>
    <arguments>
    </arguments>
</buildCommand>
```